# How to create a method what takes a generic slice where that slice of type X struct has a shared generic field

Tags: function, go, generics, nested, slice

I have two structs and my function that takes a slice of X type, as a parameter, returning the total amount of given slice

```
type Food struct {
    name string
    price float64
}

type Cloth {
    name string
    price int
}

func AddItemsAlt[T Cloth | Food](objects []T, getUnit func(obj T) float64) float64 {
    sum := 0.0
    for _, obj := range objects {
        sum += getUnit(obj)
    }
    return sum
}

func main() {
    var check = []Food {{"Pizza", 6.23}, {"Hamburgesa", 7.99}, {"Tacos", 4.34}}
    var cart = []Cloth {{"Player", 6}, {"Pants", 8}, {"Tacos de Futbol", 10}}


    check := AddItems(cart, func(obj Food) float64 {
        return obj.price
    })
}
```

I would try this and it would give me an error, given that the function is not accounting for the fact that Cloth may have the field as an int type.

Answer (score 0):

I proceeded to update my answer, adding two interfaces and putting those interfaces int the funtion

```
type Food struct {
    name string
    price float64
}

type Cloth {
    name string
    price int
}

type Amount interface {
    int | float64
}

type Item interface {
    Cloth | Food
}

func AddItemsAlt[T Item, A Amount](objects []T, getUnit func(obj T) A) A {
    sum := A(0)
    for _, obj := range objects {
        sum += getUnit(obj)
    }
    return sum
}

func main() {
    var check = []Food {{"Pizza", 6.23}, {"Hamburgesa", 7.99}, {"Tacos", 4.34}}
    var cart = []Cloth {{"Player", 6}, {"Pants", 8}, {"Tacos de Futbol", 10}}


    check := AddItems(check, func(obj Food) float64 {
        return obj.price
    })
    cartTotal := AddItems(cart, func(obj Cloth) int {
        return obj.price
    })

    fmt.Printf("The total for the shopping cart is:\t%v\n", cartTotal)
    fmt.Printf("The total for the check is:\t%.4f\n", check)

}
```